# Get the id of the checked radio button with perl

Tags: html, perl, radio-button

I am brand new to Perl.

Currently i am doing something like this to get the value of the selected radio button in the group

```
$myVariable = param('radioButtonGroupName');
```

I was wondering if it were possible to get the **ID** of that selected radio button.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible, the ID is not sent to the server.

You could set the value and the ID to the same, but that might not work for your application.

Comment: is anything apart from the value available for input elements?

Comment: Only the value is sent to the server in the request.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but not directly.

What you need to do is the following workaround:

- Create a HIDDEN input element `<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME='radio_id' VALUE=''>`
- On your radio buttons, create an `onChange` handler, which will contain JavaScript code to
  check which radio button was pressed and its ID, and populate the ID value into `radio_id`'s elemebt's value.
- Your script will then have access to the ID via `param('radio_id');`

Then again, simply matching IDs and values for radio button would be sufficient :)